# Why is more data being added to my array than should be?

Tags: matlab, sorting, debugging, data-processing

I am writing some code for data processing. The requirement is to sort the data, which comes in lists called u_B (5000 values of speed data) and P_B (5000 pieces of the related power data) into "bins" by speed, so that it is possible to calculate the mean speed and power within each bin. The code below is just trying to get the "bin" for the range of speeds 24-25m/s. What I expect to happen is that the code cycles through the u_B list, checks if each speed is within the required range, and if it is, puts it in the "bin", along with the corresponding power value. I have altered it to output the speeds it considers to be in the right range, and they seem to be all as I expect them to be, but when the bin is outputted right at the end it contains not only the data within the right range, but also a whole load of other data that does not fit within the speed range. I cannot work out why this other data is being added to the bin. If anyone can spot what I am missing I would be grateful.

```
i = 25;
inc = 1;
for n = 1:5000
     if (u_B(n) >= (i-1)) && (u_B(n) < (i + 1))
        disp(u_B(n))
        bin(inc,1) = u_B(n);
        disp(bin(inc,1))
        bin(inc,2) = P_B(n);
        inc = inc + 1
    end
end
disp(bin)
```

This shows the first set of outputs from within the if-statement, the 24.7s are the speed u_B(n) and the value that has been put into the bin, they are the same as expected, the 0 for power and 2 for inc are both fine. the list from this goes on and only contains speed values in the right range.
[screenshot of code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqyNC.png)

This shows the output of what is in the bin, the first 10 values are the ones I want to be in there, and all the rest have lower speeds, and therefore shouldn't be in the bin.
[screenshot of code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYqO7.png)

Comment: Everything works fine. I executed your code with different data and different ranges, it is correct. If you want to, I can post my code so you can compare the results. May be the bin array is not empty before the loop?

Comment: Please read about [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) in MATLAB. You code should just be `idx = u_B>=i-1 & u_B<i+1; bin = [u_B(idx), P_B(idx)]`. This is clearly more concise, and will be much quicker. This method also avoids a growing `bin` array, which is likely the cause of your issue